# How to implement non interleaved mmap (direct) access mode in Alsa for live streaming from SRAM?

Tags: mmap, alsa

I have a buffer in SRAM of size 4096 bytes which gets updated with new raw audio data periodically:

```
----------------------------------------  
| 2048 bytes of L | 2048 bytes of right|  
----------------------------------------
^                 ^
|A                |B  

NOTE: A and B are pointers to the start addresses.
```

As shown, the data is **non-interleaved stereo (16 bit samples, 44100Hz sampling rate)** and since it is in memory already, I prefer to use MMAP'ed access instead of RW (and as far as my understanding of alsa goes, it should not use a separate buffer for copying data into from this buffer).

The starting address for this buffer is fixed (say 0x3f000000 physical address) and I am MMAPing this buffer to get a virtual address pointer.

Now, how do I send data to alsa for playback and what should be my configuration?

My current **unsuccessful** way is:

```
Resample ON
Rate 44100
SND_PCM_ACCESS_MMAP_NONINTERLEAVED
channels 2
format SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE
period near 1024 frames
buffer near 2*1024 frames

void* ptr[2];
ptr[0] = A // Points to mmaped virtual address of A
ptr[1] = B // Points to mmaped virtual address of B
while(1)
{
   wait_for_new_data_in_buffer();
   snd_pcm_mmap_writen(handle, &ptr, period_size);
}
```

Extra info:
1. I am using an embedded board with arm cores and running basic linux on it.
2. This is a proprietary work related project and hence the vague-ness of this question.
3. I already know that directly MMAPing a physical address is not recommended so do not waste your time commenting about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your driver work without mmap? How did you call snd_pcm_mmap_begin()?

Comment: It works without mmap. I never called snd_pcm_mmap_begin(), as I did my own mmapping. But I am not sure whether to call it or not and hence the question.

Comment: If you are trying to bypass the driver, then you must not use `snd_`* functions. Doesn't the driver support mmap?

Comment: It does but my concern is that I want fixed memory locations for this buffer and not any random location that kernel would provide using mmap_begin.

Comment: How do you tell the driver (and the hardware) to use this buffer?

Comment: That is what I want to find out. I think in the above way I have mentioned, I am not using the same buffer area and it is copying the buffer data to a separate buffer for sound card. If this is the case, then what is the difference between the two functions snd_pcm_writen() and snd_pcm_mmap_writen().
Also, while doing the hw configuration, if I am setting the buffer size to be say 2* period_size then itn't this useless in terms of mmaping? Or shouldn't my buffer match this buffer size.

Comment: Let's say that the driver is working fine and supports MMAP non-interleaved access. Then, how would you implement the application for the above requirements. Or independently, how would you change the above implementation if you want to use a fixed buffer location.

Comment: The *driver* must tell the hardware to use the SRAM buffer. There's nothing you can do in your application.